# Enumerate certificates in Mac Keychain and check their expiry dates

Tags: macos, mac, certificate, openssl, keychain

I've looked at the man page for the `security` tool, specifically the `find-certificate` argument.

https://developer.apple.com/legacy/library/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/security.1.html

I'm using the `spaceship` gem to get a list of certs in the Apple dev portal, and I'd like to compare them the installed certs on the machine. The best comparison method seems to be creation and expiry dates.

However, I'm unable to figure out how to make `security` produce a certificate that I can then pass to `openssl` to determine creation/expiry dates.

Any guidance?

Comment: The website referred here from developer.apple.com is not available anymore.

Answer (score 3):

`-p` will dump the certs in PEM format, which can be piped to the `openssl x509` utility for display. For example:

```
security find-certificate -p -c "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" | openssl x509 -text -noout
```

Here's the full output:

```
$ security find-certificate -p -c "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" | openssl x509 -text -noout
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number: 25 (0x19)
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C = US, O = Apple Inc., OU = Apple Certification Authority, CN = Apple Root CA
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb 14 18:56:35 2008 GMT
            Not After : Feb 14 18:56:35 2016 GMT
        Subject: C = US, O = Apple Inc., OU = Apple Worldwide Developer Relations, CN = Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:ca:38:54:a6:cb:56:aa:c8:24:39:48:e9:8c:ee:
                    ec:5f:b8:7f:26:91:bc:34:53:7a:ce:7c:63:80:61:
                    77:64:5e:a5:07:23:b6:39:fe:50:2d:15:56:58:70:
                    2d:7e:c4:6e:c1:4a:85:3e:2f:f0:de:84:1a:a1:57:
                    c9:af:7b:18:ff:6a:fa:15:12:49:15:08:19:ac:aa:
                    db:2a:32:ed:96:63:68:52:15:3d:8c:8a:ec:bf:6b:
                    18:95:e0:03:ac:01:7d:97:05:67:ce:0e:85:95:37:
                    6a:ed:09:b6:ae:67:cd:51:64:9f:c6:5c:d1:bc:57:
                    6e:67:35:80:76:36:a4:87:81:6e:38:8f:d8:2b:15:
                    4e:7b:25:d8:5a:bf:4e:83:c1:8d:d2:93:d5:1a:71:
                    b5:60:9c:9d:33:4e:55:f9:12:58:0c:86:b8:16:0d:
                    c1:e5:77:45:8d:50:48:ba:2b:2d:e4:94:85:e1:e8:
                    c4:9d:c6:68:a5:b0:a3:fc:67:7e:70:ba:02:59:4b:
                    77:42:91:39:b9:f5:cd:e1:4c:ef:c0:3b:48:8c:a6:
                    e5:21:5d:fd:6a:6a:bb:a7:16:35:60:d2:e6:ad:f3:
                    46:29:c9:e8:c3:8b:e9:79:c0:6a:61:67:15:b2:f0:
                    fd:e5:68:bc:62:5f:6e:cf:99:dd:ef:1b:63:fe:92:
                    65:ab
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Certificate Sign, CRL Sign
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:TRUE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier: 
                88:27:17:09:A9:B6:18:60:8B:EC:EB:BA:F6:47:59:C5:52:54:A3:B7
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier: 
                keyid:2B:D0:69:47:94:76:09:FE:F4:6B:8D:2E:40:A6:F7:47:4D:7F:08:5E

            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points: 

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://www.apple.com/appleca/root.crl

            1.2.840.113635.100.6.2.1: 
                ..
    Signature Algorithm: sha1WithRSAEncryption
         da:32:00:96:c5:54:94:d3:3b:82:37:66:7d:2e:68:d5:c3:c6:
         b8:cb:26:8c:48:90:cf:13:24:6a:46:8e:63:d4:f0:d0:13:06:
         dd:d8:c4:c1:37:15:f2:33:13:39:26:2d:ce:2e:55:40:e3:0b:
         03:af:fa:12:c2:e7:0d:21:b8:d5:80:cf:ac:28:2f:ce:2d:b3:
         4e:af:86:19:04:c6:e9:50:dd:4c:29:47:10:23:fc:6c:bb:1b:
         98:6b:48:89:e1:5b:9d:de:46:db:35:85:35:ef:3e:d0:e2:58:
         4b:38:f4:ed:75:5a:1f:5c:70:1d:56:39:12:e5:e1:0d:11:e4:
         89:25:06:bd:d5:b4:15:8e:5e:d0:59:97:90:e9:4b:81:e2:df:
         18:af:44:74:1e:19:a0:3a:47:cc:91:1d:3a:eb:23:5a:fe:a5:
         2d:97:f7:7b:bb:d6:87:46:42:85:eb:52:3d:26:b2:63:a8:b4:
         b1:ca:8f:f4:cc:e2:b3:c8:47:e0:bf:9a:59:83:fa:da:98:53:
         2a:82:f5:7c:65:2e:95:d9:33:5d:f5:ed:65:cc:31:37:c5:5a:
         04:e8:6b:e1:e7:88:03:4a:75:9e:9b:28:cb:4a:40:88:65:43:
         75:dd:cb:3a:25:23:c5:9e:57:f8:2e:ce:d2:a9:92:5e:73:2e:
         2f:25:75:15
```

Comment: or for uncluttered dates `| openssl x509 -noout -dates`

Answer (score 1):

Or to avoid potentially complex parsing of the openssl output, you can specify just the field(s) of interest, such as:

`security find-certificate -p -c "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certification Authority" | openssl x509 -enddate -noout`

Comment: Hi and welcome AlgebraWinter. Your answer is great addition to the teppic's answer. Instead of posting it as separate entry consider editing existing solution or commenting on it --- just like dave_thompson_085 did below.